# JPQL fetch data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, fetch, jpql, criteria-api

I have the following classes.

```
class A{

    @OneToMany
    List<B> bList;
}

class B{}

class C extends A{

    @OneToMany
    List<D> dList;
}

class D{}
```

I have used lazy loading for each @OneToMany relationship.

My requirement is to fetch all data from C using "Join Fetch" as I do not want to trigger any other database calls when accessing B and D.
Basically I want to fetch C, with B and D loading "EAGER"
Something like following
"SELECT DISTINCT c FROM C c LEFT JOIN c.B"

If this is not possible with JPQL, can it be achieved with java criteria API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible,, it should be like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<C> c = cq.from(C.class);
Join<C,B> b = c.join("b", JoinType.LEFT); //left outer join
b.on(
    //define criteria here
    )   
);
cq.select(b.<String>get("field names"));

List<String> results = em.createQuery(cq)
                         .getResultList();
```

Above code needs to tweak for your requirements.